# File Not Found when trying to modify the file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am working on an application in which I need to read data from JSON file, modify the data, and write it back to the JSON file.

For reading and writing to JSON, I am using $http service of angular. When I try to get the data using `$http.get`, I am able to read the data from JSON file.

However, when I try to put data to the JSON file using, `$http.put`, I am getting 404 - Not Found.

I am using same URL in both the cases. Could someone please help me in understanding how a file that is found in GET cannot be found for PUT?

Please find below my code:

GET:

```
$http.get('data/resources.json').success(function(data) {
$scope.resources = data;
});
```

PUT:

```
$http.put('data/resources.json', [{
firstName: 'Test',
lastName : 'Test',
age      : 35     }]);
};
```

Comment: you cannot modify the file via PUT request, you will have to use File API or some other approach to modify files from javascript

Answer (score 1):

### You can't directly modify any files in server from client.

If it can be done, it will have severe security issues. Anyone can modify file in your server easily.

The way to do this is that you can add a server program in the middle to help you write the file in your server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can node be used for this purpose?

Comment: It's ok . Any server side language can be used for this purpose, like nodeJS, php, ruby, python..ans so on.